# Different outputs between Django Server and PyCharm

Tags: python, django

I am facing an issue that I get different outputs running the same code throw PyCharm and throw the Django Server.
PyCharm gives the output expected and needed, so it is an issue to fix. Because I only use PyCharm for testing.

The input string:

```
# HTML

HTML is a markup language that can be used to define the structure of a web page. HTML elements include

* headings
* paragraphs
* lists
* links
* and more!

The most recent major version of HTML is HTML5.
```

The Code is:

```
# A list of simple markdown and there html aquvalents.
# First element is the inner html/markdown second is the whole markdown, third is the starting html tag and fourth the closing html tag
regex_hugging_html = [
    [r"(?<=^#{1})[^#][^\n]*$", r"^#{1}[\s]*[^#][^\n]*$", "<h1>", "</h1>"],      # heading first level (#)
    [r"(?<=^#{2})[^#][^\n]*$", r"^#{2}[\s]*[^#][^\n]*$", "<h2>", "</h2>"],      # heading second level (##)
    [r"(?<=^#{3})[^#][^\n]*$", r"^#{3}[\s]*[^#][^\n]*$", "<h3>", "</h3>"],      # heading third level (###)
    [r"(?s)\*\*(.*?)\*\*", r"(?s)\*\*.+?\*\*", "<b>", "</b>"],                  # boldface (** **)
    [r"(?s)__(.*?)__", r"(?s)__.+?__", "<b>", "</b>"],                          # boldface (__ __)
    [r"(?s)\n{2}(.+?)(?=\n{2}|\Z)", r"(?s)(\n{2}.+?)(?=\n{2}|\Z)", "<p>", "</p>"],    # paragraphs (blank line)
]

def markdown_to_html(markdown):
    html = markdown
    for replacer in regex_hugging_html:
        # Find all occurances of the markdown expression
        for substr in re.compile(replacer[0], re.M).findall(html):
            # Replace the complet markdown expresion with the inner string surrounded by html
            html = re.compile(replacer[1], re.M).sub(replacer[2] + substr.strip() + replacer[3], html, count=1)
    return html
```

If I print the html in Pycharm I get the following Output:

```
<h1>HTML</h1><p>HTML is a markup language that can be used to define the structure of a web page. HTML elements include</p><p>* headings
* paragraphs
* lists
* links
* and more!</p><p>The most recent major version of HTML is HTML5.</p>
```

The output on my Django server looks like this:

```
<h1>HTML</h1>

HTML is a markup language that can be used to define the structure of a web page. HTML elements include

* headings
* paragraphs
* lists
* links
* and more!

The most recent major version of HTML is HTML5.
```

So you can see the missing paragraph tags from html, same as I inspect the side.

How could this be, I have really no idea?

I tried it on PyCharm as I faced the issue and as I see it should work proper.